# Dangling transaction even though commit is called (node,Sequelize v5.21.9)

Tags: node.js, express, transactions, sequelize.js, postgres-14

I have a route that uses the below shown method, in a node app that uses express.

I create a `transaction` but don't use it in the `update` method. `Sequelize` is configured to **not** use managed transactions and auto commit is set to false.

When this route is called multiple times/under load around 7 - 10 times per second (the number of calls differ), I end up with 5 or so dangling transactions even though commit is called for the transaction at the end of the method call.
*(Because of these dangling transactions, subsequent calls and my node app is not able to make anymore db calls)*

**But** if I pass the `transaction` in the `params` object this behaviour doesnt occur. **And I don't get dangling transactions.**

What can be the reason this is happening?

```js
    updateItem = (obj) => {
        this.logDebug(`Updating item - `, obj);

        return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {

            let transaction;
            try {
                transaction = await this.getTransaction();
            } catch(error) { return reject(error);


            const params = {
               where: {
                   id: obj.id
               },
               returning: true,
               plain: true
            };

            return models[modelName].
             update(obj, params).then(result => {
                   if (!result) { return result; }

                   result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result[1]));
                   return result;
                }).
                then(async (result) => {
                    await transaction.commit();
                    return resolve(result);
                }).
                catch(async error => {
                    this.logError(`Failed to update - `, error);
                    await transaction.rollback();
                    return reject(error);
                });
        });
    };
```

Causes dangling transaction.

```js
const params = {
   where: {
       id: obj.id
   },
   returning: true,
   plain: true
};
```

No dangling transactions occur.

```js
const params = {
   where: {
       id: obj.id
   },
   returning: true,
   plain: true,
   transaction
};
```

Using `Nodejs 12.4`, `Sequelize 5.21.9`, `postgres 9.x`

Just using the created `transaction` in the `params` object somehow doesn't cause dangling transaction.
While NOT using the `transaction` in the `params` causes this issue of dangling transactions.

Wanted to know the cause of this behaviour? Is it a bug with my code? Or bug with `Sequelize`?

Comment: You either use `async/await` or `then/catch` but not both, it's confusing and error-prone. Can you convert the code that starts with `return models[modelName].` into straight forward one with `await` and try/catch?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few points here;

1- there is a missing curly bracket at the end of the first line (a simple type i guess)
2- you dont't have to use the returns other than the first one
3- it is not required to use double "then" fucntion at the end
4- if json parse fails your transaction probably leak

With all these the code may be updated like this;

```
updateItem = (obj) => {
    this.logDebug(`Updating item - `, obj);

    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {

        let transaction;
        try {
            transaction = await this.getTransaction();
        } catch (error) { return reject(error); }

        const params = {
            where: {
                id: obj.id
            },
            returning: true,
            plain: true
        };

        return models[modelName].
            update(obj, params).then(async (result) => {
                try {
                    resolve(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result[1])));
                    await transaction.commit();
                } catch (err) {
                    reject(err);
                }
            }).catch(async error => {
                this.logError(`Failed to update - `, error);
                await transaction.rollback(); // an extra try catch wont hurt here...
                reject(error);
            });
    });
};
```

But things may get complicated if you want to make multiple updates in the future. I may suggest you to check [Multiple Transaction Manager's Sequelize context](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@multiple-transaction-manager/sequelize) for a clean way to arrange your transactions.